# Como cargar imágenes usando el innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

He tratado de cambiar una imagen en html usando javascript cuando el valor de p1 sea igual a 1 y el de p2 sea igual a 10 pero no me funciona con el código que estoy ocupando

```js
function verificar(){
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;

    if (p1 == 1) {
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "<img src=circuloazul.png>"
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="b">
        <img src="default.png" alt="a" id="1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="p1">
        <input type="text" id="p2">
        <button onclick="verificar()" class="button"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No crees que es por que estas comparando un string con un entero?

Comment: @Christianen en que parte?

Comment: `p1 == 1`, prueba con `parseInt(p1) == 1` y lo mismo para p2

Comment: @Christian en JavaScript `"1" == 1` será **`true`** de todas formas. ;)

Comment: Que hace esa coma `,` en la condición?

Comment: @Israel-ICM lo había olvidado, gracias :D

Comment: @Christian elimine la parte de p2, me di cuenta que no lo necesitaba pero aun sigo sin poder cambiar la imagen con innerhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si sólo necesitas cambiar el **src** de la imagen, el **innerHTML** no te sirve. Lo deberías hacer así.

```
document.getElementById("1").setAttribute('src, 'circuloazul.png');
```

Lo de **innerHTML** sirve cuando seleccionas el padre de la imagen, en ese caso es el **div.b**

Answer (score 0):

Estas cambaindo el contenido de la etiqueta img, lo que hace tu funcion es anidar una etiqueta img en otra etiqueta img:

```
 <div class="b">
        <img src="default.png" alt="a" id="1">
          <img src=circuloazul.png>
        </img>
 </div>
```

lo que no se puede interpretar en html, la respuesta correcta seria cambiar el elemento al que le estas modificando el id, en este caso sería a la class="b" no al id="1":

```
if (p1 == 1) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
    x[0].innerHTML = "<img src=circuloazul.png>"
}
```

aunque lo mas aconsejable seria que a ese div con esa clase le agregues un ID, recuerda que las clases pueden ser usadas en multiples elementos lo que ne puede generar comportamientos no deseados.